# Auto answer calls simulating a headset

Tags: android, call, headset

I'm trying to answer calls programmatically. (I'm not even going to discuss about using reflection as this only works in froyo and earlier versions). My approach was to send a headset button event to answer the call. Unfortunately this only works if a headset is connected to the phone so I send a broadcast to make the phone think that a headset is connected like this:

```
Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1); // 0 = unplugged  1 = Headset with microphone 2 = Headset without microphone
headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, null);
```

The call is successfuly answered. BUT after that I must "disconnect" the headset otherwise there is no audio (as it is redirected to the fake headset). So I send another broadcast like the previous one setting the "state" key to 0. But it doesn't work. The virtual headset is still connected. Can anyone help with this?

Seems like this headache went away with a simple project-Clean. It was just Eclipse making fun of me AGAIN. The code works fine now.

Comment: A shot in dark... could you try to use `sendBroadcast()` instead of `sendOrderedBroadcast()`...

Comment: @Anonymous - How did you handle the Audo? I have the similar problem. Simulating a Headset Audio is not easy...

Comment: I allready wrote how I handled it. The same way I simulate the headset plugged in, I simulate the headset plugged out event using "state" - > 0. Since the headset is "unplugged" audio works normaly